# VB - Running an if statement if only a certain number of checkboxes are checked?

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, groupbox

I am creating a pizza ordering system for my beginning VB class. I am able to code one topping for the pizza but when I try and add more then one topping I get the item with two toppings but also two other pizzas that have only a single toppings. Is there a way to run the if statement if only a certain number of checkboxes are selected in the group box?

```
Private Sub AddItems()

   'Declare Topping Variables 
    Dim topping1 As String = "Pepperoni"
    Dim topping2 As String = "Bacon"
    Dim topping3 As String = "Ham"

    'Declare Size Variables 
    Dim strPersonal As String = "Persoanl"
    Dim strSmall As String = "Small"
    Dim strMedium As String = "Medium"
    Dim strLarge As String = "Large"
    Dim strExLarge As String = "Extra Large"

    'Personal Single Item
    If radPersonal.Checked = True And chkPepperoni.Checked = True Then
        CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(strPersonal & " with " & topping1)
    End If
    If radPersonal.Checked = True And chkBacon.Checked = True Then
        CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(strPersonal & " with " & topping2)
    End If
    If radPersonal.Checked = True And chkHam.Checked = True Then
        CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(strPersonal & " with " & topping3)
    End If

    'Personal Two Items
    If radPersonal.Checked = True And chkPepperoni.Checked = True And chkBacon.Checked = True Then
        CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(strPersonal & " with " & topping1 & " and " & topping2)
    End If
    If radPersonal.Checked = True And chkBacon.Checked = True And chkHam.Checked = True Then
        CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(strPersonal & " with " & topping2 & " and " & topping3)
    End If
    If radPersonal.Checked = True And chkHam.Checked = True And chkPepperoni.Checked = True Then
        CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(strPersonal & " with " & topping3 & " and " & topping1)
    End If
End Sub
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VafZe.png

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should not be testing `radPersonal.Checked` six times.  You should be testing that only once and then nesting the rest.

Secondly, you should not be testing, for instance, `chkPepperoni.Checked` alone first and testing again later in combination.  If you do that then, if it is checked in combination,  it is going to match both tests.  You should be testing for the combination first and then only testing for it alone if the combination doesn't match.  Here's how I might be inclined to do it:

```
If radPersonal.Checked Then
    If chkPepperoni.Checked Then
        If chkBacon.Checked Then
            'pepperoni and bacon
        ElseIf chkHam.Checked Then
            'pepperoni and ham
        Else
            'pepperoni only
        End If
    ElseIf chkBacon.Checked Then
        If chkHam.Checked Then
            'bacon and ham
        Else
            'bacon only
        End If
    ElseIf chkHam.Checked Then
        'ham only
    End If
End If
```